# Groovy: Nested XML to Json

Tags: json, xml, groovy

I'm new to groovy. I'm facing a problem with my requirement.

My requirement is to convert nested XML to Json

Below is the Input file:

```
<root>
    <Account>
        <name>name</name>
        <age>age</age>
    </Account>
    <Assets>
        <record>
            <info>info</info>
            <details>details</details>
            <attributes>
                <property>property</property>
            </attributes>
        </record>
        <record>
            <info>info 1</info>
            <details>details 1</details>
            <attributes>
                <property>property 1</property>
            </attributes>
        </record>
    </Assets>
</root>
```

Preferred output would be like below:

```
{
 "root":[
 {"account":
 "records":{
 {"name":"name","age":"age"}
}
},
{"assets":
"records":{
"info":"info","details":"details"
},
{"attributes":{"property":"property"}}
,
{
"info":"info 1","details 1":"details 1"
},
{"attributes":{"property":"property 1"}}
}
]
}
```

In `Assets` segment we will get `n` number of records, all of the record data should be populated inside `"record":{}`.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Any inputs from you will be highly appreciated

Comment: Why in `"records":[
 {"account":
 "records":[
 {"name":"name","age":"age"}
]` is both `records` a list?

Comment: Hi Tim, yes it was expected like that. But now requirement changed and I've updated my question and output payload

Answer (score 0):

**Updated code :**

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
def text = '''
<root>
    <Account>
        <name>name</name>
        <age>age</age>
    </Account>
    <Assets>
        <record>
            <info>info</info>
            <details>details</details>
            <attributes>
                <property>property</property>
            </attributes>
        </record>
        <record>
            <info>info 1</info>
            <details>details 1</details>
            <attributes>
                <property>property 1</property>
            </attributes>
        </record>
    </Assets>
</root>
'''

def toJsonBuilder(xml){
    new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(build(new XmlParser().parseText(xml)))
}
def build(node){
    if (node instanceof String)
        return 
    def map = [ "${node.name()}" : '' ]
    if (!node.children().isEmpty() && !(node.children().get(0) instanceof String)) { 
        map.put("${node.name()}", node.children().collect{build(it)}.findAll{it != null})
    } else if (node.text() != ''){
        map.put("${node.name()}", node.text())
    }
    map
}
println toJsonBuilder(text).toPrettyString()
```

Comment: Hi Bhanu, I've tried the your code but I'm not able to encapsulate record details inside [ ] output is like this {
    "Account": {
        "name": "name",
        "age": "age"
    },
    "Assets": {
        "record": {
            "info": "info 1",
            "details": "details 1",
            "attributes": {
                "property": "property 1"
            }
        }
    }
} also code is excluding second record while converting to json. could you please help me here?

Comment: Hi Bhanu, the reason second record is excluding is because both first and second are with same name, I tried with two different names it worked. So is there any way to print data of records with same name?

Comment: @vineethB. Sorry My mistake. Now i have updated my code. have a look at this.

Comment: Hi Bhanuchander, My requirement changed a bit. Instead of generating iterated records in [ ], now they want in { }  And your code output like this. It is creating all individual records as  a single json structure 

            "Account": [
                {
                    "name": "vineeth"
                },
                {
                    "age": "21"
                }
            ]

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still interested in converting xml to json without 3rd party libraries, these two methods should produce the desired result (at least for this case).

```groovy
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.xml.XmlSlurper

String xmlToJson(String xml) {
    def parsedXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
    return JsonOutput.toJson(traverseXml(parsedXml))
}

Map traverseXml(node) {
    if( !node.childNodes() ){
        return [(node.name()): node.text()]
    }else{
        Map groups = node.children().groupBy { it.name() }
        return [(node.name()): groups.collectEntries { k, v ->
            v.size() == 1 ? traverseXml(v[0]) : [k, v.collectMany { traverseXml(it).values() }]
        }]
    }
}
```

Example of usage

```groovy
String xml = '''
<root>
    <Account>
        <name>name</name>
        <age>age</age>
    </Account>
    <Assets>
        <record>
            <info>info</info>
            <details>details</details>
            <attributes>
                <property>property</property>
            </attributes>
        </record>
        <record>
            <info>info 1</info>
            <details>details 1</details>
            <attributes>
                <property>property 1</property>
            </attributes>
        </record>
    </Assets>
</root>
'''


String json = xmlToJson(xml)
println(JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json))

assert new JsonSlurper().parseText(json) == new JsonSlurper().parseText('''
{
    "root": {
        "Account": {
            "name": "name",
            "age": "age"
        },
        "Assets": {
            "record": [
                {
                    "info": "info",
                    "details": "details",
                    "attributes": {
                        "property": "property"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "info": "info 1",
                    "details": "details 1",
                    "attributes": {
                        "property": "property 1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
''')
```